# Logic of having tabs and viewpager in the same layout file?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Starting to learn Android, I managed to make a `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`. I noticed that both TabLayout and the ViewPager layout are both childs of a `LinearLayout` in the same xml file as follows:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.barebones.barebones.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/CategoryTab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the main activity inflates the app like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Find the view pager that will allow the user to swipe between fragments
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

            // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
            TabsAdapter adapter = new TabsAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set the adapter onto the view pager
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Find the tab layout that shows the tabs
            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

            // Connect the tab layout with the view pager. This will
            //   1. Update the tab layout when the view pager is swiped
            //   2. Update the view pager when a tab is selected
            //   3. Set the tab layout's tab names with the view pager's adapter's titles
            //      by calling onPageTitle()
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        }
    }
```

I can't understand how they work together? shouldn't they be separate? Or the meaning is:

*The tabs are children of a LinearLayout, and then the rest of the space is for that ViewPager, which basically inflates a the content of the ViewPager in the remaining space of that LinearLayout?*

Answer (score 1):

The outer layout in any layout file, is the parent and sets the spatial rules for all the children. You can nest layouts or include as many template or custom views as you want. You have to think of the TabLayout and the ViewPager as 2 views inside a bigger layout. They occupy the space you will allow them to have, but can never exceed the parent's restrictions

Further note: The TabLayout is a widget that allows you to have tabs that stick under the toolbar in your app, and the Viewpager is a widget that allows you to have swipe-able views. You don't necessarily need to include them together unless you want the combination of tabs and swipe-able views. Technically the ViewPages as you've set it, will occupy the entire screen, but the TabLayout appears on top, so it seems that the pager begins where the tabs end.

Answer (score 0):

the `ViewPager` should fill up the space, which the `TabLayout` with `wrap_content` leaves:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android_layout_weight="1.00"/>
```

a `ViewPager` with `match_parent` would most likely just cause the layout's children to overlap.